# If $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(u)$ and $\theta = \mathbb{P}\{X=0\} = e^{-u}$, is $\hat{\theta}_1 = e^{-X}$ an unbiased estimator?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

1. If $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(u)$ and $\theta = \mathbb{P}\{X=0\} = e^{-u}$, is $\hat{\theta}_1  = e^{-X}$ an unbiased estimator?

Here's what I tried, is this right?
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}_1] &= \mathbb{E}[e^{-X}]  \\
&= e^{\mathbb{E}[-X]}\\
&= e^{-u} \\
&= \theta
\end{align}
$$

2. Show that $\hat{\theta}_2 = w(X)$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$, where $w(0)=1$ and $w(x)=0$ if $x> 0$.

I honestly don't know how to do this part. Thanks for the help!

3. Compare MSEs of $\hat{\theta}_1$ and $\hat{\theta}_2$ for estimating $\theta = e^{-u}$ when $u=1$ and $u=2$

So the MSE is equal to $Var() + Bias()^2$

Since $\hat{\theta}_2$ is unbiased, $MSE=Var(\hat{\theta}_2)$ My variance is $E(X^2)-E(X)^2$.

I think $E(X)^2$ is $(e^{-u})^2=e^{-2u}$, and for $E(X^2)$ do I just use the $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(w(k)^2P[X=k])$?

Comment: How do you get $\mathbb{E}[e^{-X}] = e^{-\mathbb{E}[X]}$? It looks to me — unless I messed up — that it should be $e^{\mathbb{E}[X](e^{-1}-1)}$, based on the MGF of a Poisson distribution.

Comment: I'm struggling at understanding this part, so you are probably correct. Sorry if this is obvious, but could you tell me why you use the MGF?

Comment: The MGF of $X$ is the function defined by $\Phi_X(t) = \mathbb{E} e^{tX}$, for $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Since you want to compute $\mathbb{E} e^{-X}$, which is $\Phi_X(-1)$, it is natural to look at the MGF (provided you know the expression for the [MGF of a Poisson random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples)).

Comment: That $\operatorname{E}(e^{-X}) = e^{\operatorname{E}(-X)}$ is wrong. $\qquad$

Comment: Your question stopped before it was over.  You asked whether something is an unbiased estimator.  One expects the question of ask whether something is an unbiased estimator OF SOMETHING specific.  What that something was you didn't say explicitly.

Comment: Should have been and unbiased estimator of θ, guess I forgot to put that.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\operatorname{E}[\hat \theta_1] = \operatorname{E}[e^{-X}] = M_X(-1),$$ where $M_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}]$ is the moment generating function of $X$.  For $X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(u)$, we can compute $$M_X(t) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{tx} e^{-u} \frac{u^x}{x!} = \sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{-u} \frac{(ue^t)^x}{x!} =  e^{u(e^t-1)} \sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{-(ue^t)}\frac{(ue^t)^x}{x!} = e^{u(e^t-1)},$$ hence $$\operatorname{E}[\hat\theta_1] = e^{u(e^{-1} - 1)} \ne e^{-u},$$ thus $\hat \theta_1$ is biased for the parameter $\theta = e^{-u}$, for a single observation drawn from such a distribution.

Now suppose $$\hat \theta_2 = \mathbb 1 (X = 0) = \begin{cases} 1, & X = 0 \\ 0, & X > 0. \end{cases}$$  We evaluate by the law of total probability $$\operatorname{E}[\hat\theta_2] = \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta_2 \mid X = 0] \Pr[X = 0] + \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta_2 \mid X > 0] \Pr[X > 0] = \Pr[X = 0] = \theta.$$  Thus $\hat \theta_2$ is unbiased for $\theta$.

To find the MSE of $\hat \theta_1$ and $\hat \theta_2$, we need to compute the variance of these estimators.  Note $$\operatorname{Var}[\hat\theta_1] = \operatorname{E}[\hat\theta_1^2] - \operatorname{E}[\hat\theta_1]^2,$$ and the first term is $$\operatorname{E}[\hat\theta_1^2] = \operatorname{E}[e^{-2X}] = M_X(-2) = e^{u(e^{-2}-1)}.$$  Combined with the previous computation of the expectation, we find $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{MSE}[\hat\theta_1] &= e^{u(e^{-2} - 1)} - e^{2u(e^{-1} - 1)} + (e^{u(e^{-1} - 1)} - e^{-u})^2 \\ &= e^{-2u}\left(1 - 2e^{ue^{-1}} + e^{u(e^{-2} + 1)}\right). \end{align*}$$  Since $\hat \theta_2$ is unbiased, its MSE is equal to its variance, which we compute as $$\operatorname{MSE}[\hat\theta_2] = \operatorname{Var}[\hat \theta_2] = \operatorname{E}[\hat\theta_2^2] - \operatorname{E}[\hat\theta_2]^2,$$ but note that $$\operatorname{E}[\hat\theta_2^2] = \operatorname{E}[\hat\theta_2] = \theta,$$ because $$\hat\theta_2^2 = \hat\theta_2.$$  Hence $$\operatorname{MSE}[\hat\theta_2] = \theta(1-\theta) = e^{-u} (1 - e^{-u}).$$  I leave it to you to finish the exercise to determine which MSE is smaller for $u = 1$ and $u = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

In part (1) there is no theorem that states $\mathbb E(\exp Y) = \exp \mathbb E(Y)$. You can't move the expectation past the exponential. Instead, use the general formula:
$$
\mathbb E(g(X))=\sum_{k=0}^\infty g(k)P(X=k),
$$
which is valid for any function $g$ when $X$ takes values $0, 1, 2,\ldots$. For part (1) the formula gives
$$
\mathbb E(e^{-X}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}P(X=k)
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}e^{-u}{u^k\over k!}
= e^{-u}\sum_{k=0}^\infty {(u e^{-1})^k\over k!}
= e^{-u}e^{u(e^{-1})}
= e^{u(e^{-1}-1)},
$$
agreeing with the answer of @Clement C. For part (2) the formula gives
$$
\mathbb E(w(X)) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty w(k)P(X=k)
=\sum_{k=0}w(k)P(X=k) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty w(k)P(X=k)
$$
Can you take it from there?

For part (3), to get the variance of a generic estimator $\hat\theta$, you are correct to use:
$$
V(\hat\theta) = E(\hat\theta^2) - [E(\hat\theta)]^2.
$$
You already calculated $E(\hat\theta)$ in parts (1) and (2). As for $E(\hat\theta^2)$: For part (1) we have $\hat\theta_1:=e^{-X}$, so
$$
E[\hat\theta_1^2] = E[(e^{-X})^2] = E[e^{-2X}] = E[g(X)]
$$
where $g(x):=e^{-2x}$, while for part (2) we have $\theta_2:=w(X)$, so
$$E[\hat\theta_1^2] = E[w(X)^2] = E[w(X)]$$
since $w(x)$ takes values only $0$ and $1$. So in both cases you can apply the $\mathbb Eg(X)$ formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So would it be w(0)*P(w=0) + sum(w(k)*P(X=k), which is 1*e^-u.  So it is unbiased!

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Great! I added one more part, would really appreciate it if you could give me another tip. My attempt could be way off for all I know, so sorry in advance!

Comment: You are correct to use the variance formula, but it's wrong to say $E[(e^{-X})^2] = [E(e^{-X})]^2$, because there's no theorem that states $E(Y^2)=[E(Y)]^2$.

Comment: Thanks again. You really made this clear for me. Can't tell you enough how much I appreciate it!